# Payment declined. Please add a valid payment method for this amount on your computer. (PayPal live mode in iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, payment-gateway

When i try to pay with paypal in Live environment, it is showing this error.

severity: None
category: Application
errorId: 589009
message: Payment declined. Please add a valid payment method for this amount on your computer.

```
    PayPal *ppMEP = [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-8NN51090BJ5943514" forEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];
    ppMEP.feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.recipient = @"xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"; //I am using recipient business email id
    payment.merchantName = @"xxxxxx";
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
    payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
    payment.description =@"Gift";

    [ppMEP checkoutWithPayment:payment];
    [payment release];
```

Comment: You can use just In-app purchase in your app

Comment: are you using this example? https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: I am using this MPL..https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/blob/gh-pages/MPL/PayPalMPL_2-1-0_iPhone_DevelopersPackage.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got the same issue and received response from PayPal.

Hello Sudheer,

Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Support.

This appears to be a standard payment decline and not a code based issue.

Please verify the funding method attached to your account and attempt to complete your payment again.

Thank you!